# Why did Hanuman fight his son?

Tags: hanuman

I recently found out that lord Hanuman has a son through the question asked on this site called "Did lord Hanuman have a son".

After that, a comment I saw said that he had to fight his son to enter a place. Why did he have to fight him even after he had found his son?

Comment: His son, Magardhwaj, was the guard of Ahiravan. Hanuman hi went to save Raam ji and Lakshman ji, and the entrance was guarded by his son. This is ehy they fought.

Comment: @ABcDexter--Who is  wife of Hanumanji? Hanuman is confirmed bachelor according to the hearsays from puranic story tellers.

Comment: What are your sources for the claim that Lord Hanumāna had a son?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true that Lord Hanuman have a son. Name of his son is **"Makardhwaja"**, which belongs to Samundra (Sea) and Patal.

The story about **Lord Hanuman and Makardhwaja fight is mentioned in Adbhut Ramayan**. According this Story:

> When King Ravana was sure about his defeat in The war with Lord Rama,
>   He approached Ahiraavan to help him. Ahiraavan was the king of Patal
>   Lok, and Makardhwaja is the Protector of Patal Lok.
>
> When, Ahiravana tricked and Kidnapped Shri Rama and Laxman and took
>   Rama and Lakshmana to Patala. Lord Hanuman followed them to their
>   rescue, where at the gate of Patala Lok he met his Son "Makardhwaja"
>   when Makardhwaja introduced himself as the son of Hanuman and told the
>   story about his birth, Lord Hanuman Accepted him as his Son.
>
> Then Sri Hanuman told him to save Sri Rama and Laxman, But
>   "Makardhwaja" said that Ahiravana is the Master of Patallok and as you
>   are doing your duty i am also serving my master to protect the patal
>   lok.

That`s why i can`t allow you to enter in Patallok, then to save the life of Sri Rama and Laxman, Lord Hanuman fought and defeated his son "Makardhwaja".

You can watch this Video in Hindi which describes **[Panchmukhi Hanuman Story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76ph4QoDs0M)**, the Complete Story and Birth Details of "Makardhwaja" and his Mother.

Comment: Where is it mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana that Hanuman had a son?

Comment: Story of birth of Makardhwaj is associated with Hanuman burning down Lanka.  When Hanuman was extinguishing the fire on this tail, a drop of sweat fell in the ocean which was swallowed by a crocodile (makara in Sanskrit).

As a result of which, a child was born to the makara (crocodile). The child born to a crocodile was named as ‘Makardhwaj’.

Comment: But this is not present in Valmiki Ramayana. This must be present  in later day version of  Ramayana. Please modify the sentence "Yes, according Valmiki Ramayana, it is true that Lord Hanuman have a son."

Comment: No proper sources attached.